# jQuery empty but exclude a certain element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector, removechild

I try to `empty()` a div but exclude a specific selector.

What [I've tried](http://fiddle.jshell.net/KLh4E/1/) so far:

```
$('.modal').find('.close').nextAll().empty();
$('.modal').find(':not(.close)').empty();
$('.modal').not('.close').empty();
$('.modal:not(.close)').empty();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal">
  <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
  ...I've the need to be removed...
</div>
```

Comment: Show us an example of the HTML please.

Comment: Already done, look at the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/KLh4E/1/)...

Comment: Your HTML should be in the *question itself*, otherwise when JS Fiddle falls over (and it does, semi-frequently) this question becomes useless, as a resource to others with the same, or similar, problems.

Comment: @DavidThomas Ok, I've to accept! Thanks for the edit :-*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be done like this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/KLh4E/11/

```
$(".modal").contents().filter(function(){
    return !$(this).is('.close');
}).remove();
```

Comment: @ErickAstoOblitas I'm really not sure how link is related to question?

Comment: @yckart If your '...I've the need to be removed...' were a set of defined elements like input, span, etc
You can use `$('input', $('.modal')).remove()`, `$('span', $('.modal')).remove()`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about a bug, but the easiest way I could see to accomplish this is:

```
var el = $('.close');
$('.modal').empty().append(el);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/davidThomas/KLh4E/2/).

A slightly better approach (on the incorrect assumption of multiple `.close` elements):

```
$('.modal').each(
  function(){
    var that = $(this),
        el = that.find('.close');
    that.empty().append(el)
  });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/davidThomas/KLh4E/4/).

A combination of using jQuery `each()` and a plain-JavaScript function:

```
function fratricide(el) {
  while (el.previousSibling) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el.previousSibling);
  }
  while (el.nextSibling) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el.nextSibling);
  }
}

$('.close').each(

function() {
  fratricide(this);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/davidThomas/KLh4E/10/).

And a [JS Perf comparison of approaches](http://jsperf.com/javascript-fratricide). Unsurprisingly the use of plain-JavaScript speeds things up appreciably, even though it is, I think, pretty ugly to read (though I'm unsure how much prettier it could realistically become).

Interestingly (to me, anyway, now that I've updated the previously-linked JS Perf) using a variable to store the reference to `el.parentNode` makes negligible difference, presumably because despite saving a reference to the element/node the DOM is still having to be accessed in order to find the `el.previousSibling` node?

Comment: mhh, not really elegant, eh?!

Comment: No, that's what I'm exploring now... =) Does your actual page have multiple `.close` elements? (I'm assuming it does...)

Comment: Thanks! 'T is still unpretty, though... =)

Comment: sure, but the thought is that counts ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one: http://fiddle.jshell.net/KLh4E/3/

```
var div = $('.modal').clone().find('a');
$('.modal').empty().html(div);
```

Comment: mhh, not really elegant, eh?!

Comment: So how do you want it to be? bit more in one liner.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't match textnodes. The text in your example isn't seen as a node contained within .modal; as such it cannot be removed through "selecting all nodes except some other node". Wrapping the text in a simple `<span>` [will do the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/KLh4E/9/).